# C++: What does std::vector<I> mask(n_col, -1); mean?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm translating a bit of C++ code (it's a long time since I looked at any!!). I'm not sure what this means:

```
std::vector<I> mask(n_col, -1);
```

Is it creating a vector of length `n_col` filled with the value `-1`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: just google for syntax of vector declaration

Comment: is the type `I` a standard stl type? (can't google single characters ....)

Comment: @tdc: No, `I` is not a standard type; it will be defined somewhere in your code.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks (not my code btw!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It creates a `std::vector` of items of type `I` of length `n_col` with all items initialized from `-1`.

Comment: @tdc : heh - it's just being in the right place, at the right time.

Comment: To be pedantic, the elements are *constructed/initialized from* `-1`, nothing can be said about the actual values of the items, which are dependent of the actual type `I`.

Comment: @rubenvb : that's what I said "with all items initialized to `-1`". Or are you talking about the usage of the word "to" instead of "from" ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker yes, I did say `pedantic`. I think everyone that's a little familiar with C++ will know what you meant though, it might be confusing to beginners.

Comment: @rubenvb : adapted the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).

Yes, it creates a vector of length `n_col` with `n_col` repetitions of `I(-1)`.

Comment: Not exactly: with `n_col` repetitions of `I(-1)`.

In fact, the declaration assumes that the vector value type `I` can be initialized with an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The code is using Constructor (2) from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), and gives you a `vector<I>` of `n_col` elements, all constructed from value `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

[The reference documentation says yes, you're correct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/). 
Although the constructor takes three arguments, the third - Allocator - is optional.

Answer (score 0):

It will construct a single I from -1, the others will all be copied from that one.

If you create a type that has an implicit constructor from int, and prints when that constructor gets invoked, then create a vector this way of a size of say 10, you will see your print happens just once, not 10 times.

e.g.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  int m_value;
   Foo() : m_value( 0 ) {}
   Foo( int i ) : m_value( i )
   {
        std::cout << "Constructor from int\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Foo> foovec( 10, -1 );
}
```